# Kohana Auth module login system

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-3.2, kohana-auth

I recently started working at a company that uses `Kohana` with the `Auto-modeler` module and `k0stache` module.
And I am currently making a login system but I can find some decent information about using the `Auth` in combination with `Auto-modeler` and `k0stache`. And I have looked at the `Kohana` , `k0stache` and `Auto-modeler` documentation

Can anyone of you help me or tell me what steps to take.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of Auth tutorials, plenty. Try this [demo application](http://github.com/ddrake/kohana_demo/blob/master/README.markdown). This is a full demo application with everything you would need. Enjoy.